# Is it bad practice to pass controls as parameters

Tags: c#

For example I have a method in the `Booking` class that updates a `dataGridView` control in the `BookingForm`.

```
Booking booking = new Booking();
booking.getBookings(dataGridViewBooking);
```

Similarly:

```
booking.getTables(comboBoxTables);
```

Is it bad practise to use controls as parameters? I have changed all the `textBox` parameters to strings and passed `textBox.Text` but how would something similar be done with other controls or are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Well, yes, it is an opinion and we need more context but in general I think that UI code should address UI related issues like filling a DataGridView. Business logic that has the job to retrieve data should return this data in a form or another to the UI layer

Comment: primarily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass controls as parameters. They are normal objects that can be passed around.

It's questionable to pass UI objects to some kind of business logic, though. The business logic is not supposed to know anything about the UI.

Also, if you have the option of passing `textBox.Text` instead that simplifies the logic of that method. Probably, that method should not concern itself with extracting data from the UI. The SRP applies.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you try to detangle the control from the data.  i suggest you read up on [`BindingList`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23222/BindingList-Example) .  Create an intermediate record class that has all the fields you want to display, each field is one Property. Then create a. `BindingList` of that type and assign it to the `DataSource` of your grid.